# Can I use animated transition bindings in a containerless knockout element?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

If i have a set of DOM elements constructed with a containerless foreach, is it possible to use the knockout animated transitions with them? E.g. afteradd, aftermove, afterremove.

Something like:

```
<!-- ko foreach: somelist(), afterAdd: afterAddCallback -->
    <div>dom element for list item</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I idiotically screwed up my test code. The code below will generate messages on the console using either a div (commented out) or the virtual tags. So, yes.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  myItems: ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']),
  yellowFadeIn: function(element, index, data) {
    console.debug("Something");
  },
  addItem: function() {
    this.myItems.push('New item');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!--div data-bind="foreach: {data:myItems, afterAdd: yellowFadeIn}" -->
<!-- ko foreach: { data: myItems, afterAdd: yellowFadeIn } -->
  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
  <!-- /div -->

<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
```